# Jenkins script failed

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing Jenkins pipeline script and have an error:

```
No such DSL method '$' found among steps
```

At this line:

```
 + mkdir -p /scratch/jenkins-build-results/Release
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.
I think I work with params incorrectly, but where?

Script excerpt:

```
         stage('Build and install')
            {
                steps
                {
                    script
                    {
                        buildAndInstall( preset: 'gcc_release', destPath: getReleaseDestPath() )
                    }
                }
            }
    
    def buildAndInstall(params)
    {
        bash("cmake --preset ${params.preset}", "Configure")
        bash("cmake --build --preset ${params.preset}", "Building")
    
        sh(script:"mkdir -p ${params.destPath}", label: "Creating a directory for ${params.preset} installation")
    
        def buildDir = getBuildPath( preset : ${params.preset} )
        sh(script:"cmake --install ./${buildDir} --prefix ${params.destPath}", label: "Installation")
    }
    
    def bash(String cmd, String label)
    { 
        sh(script:"#/usr/bin/env bash\nset -euo pipefail\n${cmd}", label: label)
    }
    
    def getReleaseDestPath()
    {
        return "/scratch/jenkins-build-results/Release"
    }


    def getBuildPath( params )
    {
        // 'build' suffix is hardcoded in the cmake presets
        return "build/${params.preset}"
    }
```

Comment: Is this your entire `Jenkinsfile`? It is not a valid `Jenkinsfile` as shared in the question.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard No, this is Pipeline script

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line:

```
def buildDir = getBuildPath( preset : ${params.preset} )
```

It should be the following:

```
def buildDir = getBuildPath( preset : params.preset )
```